# Importing Java classes into Groovy template (Play framework 1.x)

Tags: java, groovy, playframework, playframework-1.x

Is it possible to import Java classes into a Groovy template while using Play framework to avoid using fully qualified paths?

Current:

```
<div>
    *{ Loop through enum values.}*
    #{list items:package1.package2.package3.SampleEnum.values, as:'enumValue'}
        ...
    #{/list}
</div>
```

Desired:

```
%{
    import package1.package2.package3.SampleEnum 
}%
<div>
    *{ Loop through enum values.}*
    #{list items:SampleEnum.values, as:'enumValue'}
        ...
    #{/list}
</div>
```

Comment: david can't comment on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, sadly not. You could set the enum values in a different template and inherent those separate friendly named values but that is just a hack.

PS miss you